# Induction Proof Verification

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I want to prove that $x^{2n}=(-x)^{2n}$. Here is my attempt, is this correct?
Step 1. $x^{2(1)}=(-x)^{2(1)}$ Which is true
Step 2. Assume: $x^{2k}=(-x)^{2k}$
Step 3. Proving $x^{2(k+1)}=(-x)^{2(k+1)}$
$x^{2(k+1)}= x^{2k+2}=x^{2k}x^{2}=(-x)^{2k}x^{2}=(-x)^{2k+2}=(-x)^{2(k+1)} $

Comment: Yes, it looks good for me.

Answer (score 0):

correction
$x^{2(k+1)}=x^{2k+2}=x^{2k}x^{2}=(-x)^{2k}(-x)^{2}=(-x)^{2k+2}=(-x)^{2(k+1)}$

same way you would show $(x+5)^{k+1}=(x+5)^{k}(x+5)$

this step doesn't prove anything $(-x)^{2k}x^{2}=(-x)^{2k+2}$

Comment: If you look at Step 2, I assume that $x^{2k} = (-x)^{2k}$, so I just plugged it in.

Comment: thing is a lot of things are obvious but the point of a proof is to show it , you cant skip that step

Comment: Part of the inductive proof is to assume that it works for $k$, which is my step 2.